# Task failure in DataprocCreateClusterOperator when i add metadata

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

This is my cluster config, where i have added some connector metadata

> cluster_config = {
> "project_id": project_id,
> "cluster_name": cluster_name,
> "region": region,
> "cluster_config": {
> "master_config": {
> "num_instances": 1,
> "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-4",
> },
> "worker_config": {
> "num_instances": 0,
> "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-4",
> },
> },
> "metadata":{"gcs-connector-version": '2.1.1',
> "bigquery-connector-version": '1.1.1',
> "spark-bigquery-connector-version": '0.17.2'}
> }

`create_task = DataprocCreateClusterOperator( task_id="create_dataproc_cluster", dag=dag, **cluster_config )`

so when i run in ariflow composer i get very non-specific error that above task failed.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> grpc._cython.cygrpc._store_c_metadata
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
> [2024-03-30 07:48:37.855695+00:00] {taskinstance.py:1346} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.

when i don't give metadata it runs fine, but adding metadata causes failure of the task.